# Showing animated "loading" gif before the actual html content appears in Lightbox/Facebox

Tags: jquery, facebox, animated-gif

Hey guys, I'm trying to show an animated gif for 2 seconds before the actuall content appears in a lightbox (Facebox). How can make this happen?

The Facebox module gets triggered after a form submit and so far I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#submitform').submit(function() {
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post('/file.php', function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

The loader is placed in like this:

```
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
    The content...

<div id="loader"><img src="http://notifly.se/notifly/images/loader.gif"></div></div>
```

Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem in the Facebox documentation.

You need to wrap your code around:

```
$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { *//code here//* }
```

Now all jQuery works inside of Facebox.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
$('#submitform').submit(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$('#loader').show();},0);
        $.post('/file.php', function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Your loader div is a child of the info div which is not displayed. Put your loader div out side of it. Sorry, I should have noticed that earlier!

Comment: The lightbox only loads content within the info-div. If I put the loader outside of that will it still show inside of the lightbox?

Comment: You should control the placement of your divs using CSS and make it appear that the loader is 'inside' the content

Comment: Tried putting it outside of the info div but now it shows as soon as I load the page.

Comment: You should set the style to `display:none;` in that case

Answer (score 0):

I would write the following functions.

```
 function showLoadingDialog(){
     $('#loader').show();

     //Second parameter is in Ms
     //setTimeout will delay the function call for the time specified
     setTimeout('showRealContent()', 2000)
 }

 function showContent(){
      $('#loader').hide();
      $('info').show();
 }
```

Then you can just call showLoadingDialog() from your event

Comment: The code looks good but doesn't work. When I do an onClick and call showLoadingDialog() on form submission nothing shows.

Comment: Guess this doesn't work cuz the loader div is inside the info div which is called when onclick="jQuery.facebox({ div: '#info' });". So if I call showLoadingDialog(); Facebox isn't called at all.

Comment: Yes I would seperate the divs.